# IE8 compatibility mode

Tags: ie8-compatibility-mode

I've created a website that displays correctly in all browsers including IE8 when viewed from my local server i.e. http://localhost

However when I view the website from another machine, http://pc5008 for example, IE8 goes into what seems like compatibility mode and looks terrible.

**Extra Info**
When viewed from the localhost IE8 gives an option to view in compatibility mode. If I choose this option it looks the same as when viewed on the non-localhost i.e. terrible.

When viewed on the non-localhost IE8 doesn't show the option to view in compatibility mode. (compatibility mode under Tools is greyed out)

Also, everything validates as XHTML 1.0 Strict.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with the subject, however as I know IE chooses it's mode (standard/quirks-mode) based on doctype declaration. Check if your doctype is correct.

Maybe this article will help: [Activating Browser Modes with Doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/).

If the problem is eventually with doctype, try declaring it html5 style:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In turns out that IE8 has an option under `Tools\Compatibility View Settings\` called 'Display intranet sites in Compatibility View'.  Disabling this feature fixes my problem.

Another solution is to add the following line to the head:

```
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8">
```

This overrides the setting.

Comment: It has to be <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> otherwise if you open your site in IE 9.0 it would trigger the IE 8 mode instead of IE 9.0 but there is catch, if you use X-UA-Compatible in the markup, you would not be able to validate your (X)HTML code so best way to set it up using server side config headers in .htaccess/web.config